# How to export Bokeh view to Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, pdf-generation, bokeh

I have a Flask web app that uses Bokeh to deliver interactive charts. My end goal is to export whatever the current Bokeh view is to Matplotlib (so that I can create a printable pdf file after that). This would include how the current axes look like after the user zooms and pans. Is there a way to export that data so that I can create those Matplotlib charts behind the scenes? (Printing the page directly or printing to pdf results in low-quality and blurred charts.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to export bokeh to matplotlib. Actually you can do it otherway. You can create matplotlib plot, save, and after that you can  [export matplotlib to bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/compat.html#bokeh.mpl.to_bokeh). I think this is the best option. Eventually you can export bokeh plot as png but it still would not solve problem with quality

Comment: Thanks for the input. I thought about doing it the other way around (with matplotlib first) but part of what I'm trying to capture in the final output is all the manipulations that the user has created (zoom, pan, etc.) - which won't be part of the initial matplotlib foundation.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Only option I see is to export to png manually or using PhantomJS [link](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/8vNYGHt8K3s). Maybe some day there will be a possibility for better export

Comment: Hopefully - we'll see with version 1.0. I saw that some contributors are considering embedding PhantomJS. The problem is that as it is right now, if you use the screen capture method, it captures the screen as if you reloaded the page fresh without user manipulations.

Comment: Maybe you can use selenium for user manipulations. Not sure if some options work on bokeh graph bot maybe there is a chance

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I'll see if there's a way to extract any signals that tell what manipulations have been done so that I can replicate them using selenium.